# How to change CELL's value depending on same CELL [EXCEL]

Tags: excel

I've been searching and I'm going crazy that I'm not understand how this works....

So I've left an html table to examplify what i mean.

I just wanted to write 110 or 113 on the Starting day and get that value tranform to 10h00 or 11h30 and depending on that value having the End of the day to be 22h00 or 20h30

--

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <style>
   table, th, td {
      border: 1px solid black;
 
   }
   
  </style>
 </head>
<body>

 <h2>Bordered Table Example</h2>
 <p>A simple Table Example.</p>

 <table cellspacing="10">
    <tr>
       <th>Table Template</th>
       <th>Monday</th> 
       <th>Tuesday</th>
   <th>Wednesday</th>
       <th>Thursday</th>
       <th>Friday</th> 
       <th>Saturday</th>
   <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Opening</th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
       <th> </th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Lunch Time</th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
       <th> </th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Closing</th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
       <th> </th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
    </tr>
  
    <tr>
       <th>Incial Input</th>
       <th>Monday</th> 
       <th>Tuesday</th>
   <th>Wednesday</th>
       <th>Thursday</th>
       <th>Friday</th> 
       <th>Saturday</th>
   <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Opening</th>
       <th> 100 </th> 
       <th> 100 </th>
   <th> 113 </th>
       <th> 113 </th>
       <th> 113 </th> 
       <th> 113 </th>
   <th> 100 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Lunch Time</th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
       <th> </th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Closing</th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
       <th> </th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
       <th>Final Result</th>
       <th>Monday</th> 
       <th>Tuesday</th>
   <th>Wednesday</th>
       <th>Thursday</th>
       <th>Friday</th> 
       <th>Saturday</th>
   <th>Sunday</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Opening</th>
       <th> 10h00 </th> 
       <th> 10h00 </th>
   <th> 11h30 </th>
       <th> 11h30 </th>
       <th> 11h30 </th> 
       <th> 11h30 </th>
   <th> 10h00 </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Lunch Time</th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
       <th> </th>
       <th> </th> 
       <th> </th>
   <th> </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <th>Closing</th>
       <th> 22h00 </th> 
       <th> 22h00 </th>
   <th> 20h30 </th>
       <th> 20h30 </th>
       <th> 20h30 </th> 
       <th> 20h30 </th>
   <th> 22h00 </th>
    </tr>
 </body>
</html>
```

--

Comment: Doable with the `Worksheet_Change` event in VBA.

Comment: or format the cells: `##\h#\0`

Comment: @ScottCraner - yep didn't even think of that. I'd almost say that's a valid answer.

Comment: @BigBen and ScottCraner due to the limitations of the computer, i cannot use VBA...

Comment: Then format the cells. Then use a formula for the ending cells.

Comment: @BigBen when you say "Then format the cells. Then use a formula for the ending cells" you mean format as describred by Scott `##\h#\0`?

Comment: Yes that is correct